# CAS SSO automatically log in

Tags: authentication, automation, single-sign-on, cas

i want an automaticalle login in my services when the user is already logged in into cas.
At the moment i must click the login button in every service manually to login.
My goal is when i'am logged in into cas and i join for example my jenkins service my user logged in automatically without clicking the log in button.

Can someone help me?

Comment: I think one solution is to check if a cookie with the right pattern is set and if thats true an automatic redirect to the login is one way?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using something like Spring Security or similar to manage it, then it can do it automatically for you. But since you seems to be making a Single Page Application(as you've said that you're needing a loggin button), and by going with that assuption, you'd need to have that login anyways. Except of course if you've set a script to check if there's a valid cookie already. More details appreciated(sorry, can't just comment)